# youtube api fails when video has commercials

Tags: youtube-api

I've been creating a website that uses youtube videos.  To test it, I just use a database of urls that I got from youtube.  What I find is that my use of the youtube api works with some videos, but not with others.  So to try and figure out why, I did a right click on the videos, and I found that both types are flash videos.  However, I find that my first 'seek' with the videos that have commercials stuck at the beginning, does not work, even though when the video is embedded in my iframe, the commercial does not appear.
I think this is a bug.
There is a slight possibility that its not the commercials, but something else about these videos, because I have a fairly small sample.
Thanks,

Comment: Could you post the ID of one of the working videos and one of the non-working videos? I don't think the ad prerolls should in any way affect the API on their own, so it'd be helpful to look at what you're looking at for what else might be in there.

Comment: Can you also provide a live sample of your integration? Ideally you'd pare something down to just the minimum to reproduce the issue, and post is somewhere public, like jsfiddle.net

Comment: This one does not work:Acting techniques v=beoCle-7xvU
This one does work:        carolina song v=PlVoFytdG-w
I will port the webpage later, if I get permission.  We're trying to keep the idea secret until we sell it.

Comment: I tried it again, and its gets even stranger.  It works with IE.  But it does not work right with chrome.  Its actually doing the SEEK correctly, but no image appears, I just hear the audio. For debugging, I used the javascript console, and I got several errors, which I paste below.

Comment: here:
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with http://www.youtube.com/embed/beoCle-7xvU?hl=en&fs=1&autoplay=0&autohide=0&enablejsapi=1&modestbranding=1&playerapiid=ourvideoid&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0.  trustedhost: http://s.ytimg.com/yts/swfbin/ad3-vflxuaxGJ.swf
 Domains, protocols and ports must match.
Loaded xlb file for locale - en succeed
en_US is not supported. Attempting to trim locale.
attempted to add unknown field. Name=use_request_token_for_video value=true non-camel_case_key=use_request_token_for_video
Font still too big even at minFontSize
AdData not defined.

Comment: I've been using asp.net forms, so I moved the youtube video iframe outside the form tag, and I now at least see the video in chrome, but chrome freezes and will not scroll down.  Firefox will scroll down, but the initial seek fails.  If I repeat the seek, it works.  Internet Explorer seems to work OK.  I will try to put up a minimal example that shows the problem.  I'll do that here, and in a separate post.

Comment: This webpage is a test version, that does not work with chrome.
http://www.rateforsuccess.com/test2.aspx.